# What is the difference between web hosting and self hosting?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

Could someone please explain the difference between web hosting and self hosting? I am looking for an answer in context of Asp.net WebAPI. But general explanation would also be helpful.

Any links can also help!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Web Hosting means to deploy your project to a web server, usually IIS. When Self hosting, you create a host ny yourself, usually a Windows Service. Both approaches are different. While you can use the web servers infrastructure and admin tools for the earlier, you need to provide some of these yourself when Self Hosting. On the other hand, you can tailor configuration and deployment of your service to the requirements and background of your users. 
The ASP.NET Web API documentation at http://www.asp.net/web-api is a good starting point. There are various tutorials, both on Web Hosting and some special ones on [Hosting](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/hosting-aspnet-web-api) (Self Hosting / Azure).

Comment: And now with Owin we have even more hosting options.